# Are Cellular Automata models compatible with the Holographic Principle?

Tags: computer-science, physics, quantum-mechanics, discrete-geometry, cellular-automata

Cellular Automata are discrete models which have a regular finite dimensional grid of cells, each in one of a finite number of states, such as on and off.

There are various scientists that have combined Cellular Automata with the Holographic Principle (like nobel laureate Gerard 't Hooft, Seth Lloyd, Paola Zizzi...etc) to describe the universe.

For example, Lloyd's model is based in a quantum computer or quantum CA which would produce all laws of physics of the universe. Since quantum computers could be compatible with all Cellular Automata (i.e a quantum computer could reproduce all CA behaviour), wouldn't that mean that all Cellular Automata can be represented by his quantum computer (based on the Holographic Principle)?

Are all Cellular Automata related to the Holographic Principle? Can we mathematically represent all Cellular Automata models in terms of Holography?

Comment: This is too abstract and philisophical therefore it may be a misfit for MSE.